# Can I use CoffeeScript to write my Electron (Atom Shell) application?

Tags: coffeescript, electron

Does anything special have to be done to get Electron to run my `main.coffee` file? I have a `main.js` file (that works) that I converted to CoffeeScript (hence `main.coffee`), but when I run `Electron main.coffee` I get an error like the following:

```
App threw an error when running [SyntaxError: /Users/foo/develop/electron/main.coffee:13
app.on('window-all-closed', ->
                             ^
Unexpected token >]
```

I can only assume this is a CoffeeScript issue, since when I commented the offending code with CoffeeScript's block comment (`###`), I got the following:

```
App threw an error when running [SyntaxError: /Users/foo/develop/electron/main.coffee:13
###
^
Unexpected token ILLEGAL]
```

I added `coffee-script` to my packages.json as a dependency, and made sure it was installed to my local node_modules directory like my other application dependencies, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: I'd guess that you'd have to transpile your CoffeeScript to JavaScript before handing it to Electron.

Comment: Does Electron support running CS directly? If not: have a file watcher compile to JS automatically, then you're just executing regular JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do it (atom doesn't ship with a coffeescript compiler), but you can use the watch option of coffeescript,

> -w, --watch        watch scripts for changes and rerun commands

For example:

`coffee -w main.coffee`  in your case.

Answer (score 16):

I think, the main file `main.js` has to be javascript. But you can require a coffee file, for example `application.coffee`, from there using [coffee-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coffee-script).

### main.js

```
// main.js
require('coffee-script').register();
require('./application')
```

### application.coffee

```
# application.coffee
app = require('app')
BrowserWindow = require('browser-window')
# ...
```

### Installing coffee-script

Include it in your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.33.1",
    "coffee-script": "~1.10.0"
  }
}
```

And run:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 7):

I've recently discovered that instead of transpiling to Javascript, you can do something like:

```
<script>
  require('coffee-script').register();
  require('../src/app/boot');
```

and then in src/app/boot.coffee you can use regular CoffeeScript :)

I found it in the app https://github.com/postcasio/hearthdash so there are more examples there.