# NodeJS / NPM - Remote package bug

Tags: node.js, npm, dialog, electron, fs

I'm building an electron app that needs an open/save dialog window.

I'm following this guide online: [Standard Dialogs in Electron](http://mylifeforthecode.com/getting-started-with-standard-dialogs-in-electron/) which uses the `remote` package.

I'm getting a syntax error with one of the dependency files within the remote package, shown below:

```
Unexpected token >: node_modules/remote/libs/remote.coffee:8
```

Line 8 is `module.exports = (opts = {}) ->`, probably supposed to be `=>`. If I change that, I get an `Unexpected identifier` error instead. This leads me to think there's some kind of ES6 support issue here.

Are there any troubleshooting steps I could take to help narrow down the issue?

Or alternatively, suggestions for a different electron-compatible package for open file/save file dialog windows (mac).

Comment: Looks like that dependency is coffee script - did you check out this question- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292835/can-i-use-coffeescript-to-write-my-electron-atom-shell-application

Comment: @madebydavid Good find, but it's not solving my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by an update issue regarding the require syntax. The solution is the following:

```
// use these lines instead to set up dialog instead of the remote package.
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const dialog = remote.dialog;
```

Fix courtesy of [this Github comment](https://github.com/m1ga/ti-create/issues/12#issuecomment-278318337)